# distribute objects evenly across containers based on multiple values

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to code this in python but unless there are specific libraries that will accomplish what I want this is more of an algorithm question.

This is my first post here: thanks in advance for your patience with any incorrect etiquette / form.

Last, it seems likely there are existing terms / algorithms / code for what I'm trying to accomplish but haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for. If this isn't a new problem I'd be grateful for links to the existing or similar ones.

Now the question: I have a series of objects, each with two numbers in them, and need to move the objects into some number of collections so that the sums of the two numbers in each collection is roughly equal.

To put it in real terms: I have a list of storage folders, each row with a size and inode count. I want to create some number of lists of folder names, with each list effectively containing the same subtotal of size/count.

Thanks again for your input...

Comment: You should probably post this to [programmers.se]. See [Where should I post questions about algorithms: Stack Overflow or Programmers SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se)

Comment: Look up the partition-problem or subset-sum problem. Apart from that your question is too broad. Example: you could minimize the mean absolute difference or the mean squared difference.

Comment: Thank you! Partition Problem is exactly the situation I'm facing, and appears to be a straightforward one when one summed variable is involved. Not sure how to go about it when two sums are tracked.